# Using substitute to do variable substitutions inside R expressions

Tags: r, expression, substitution

I would like to use `substitute()` to do variable substitutions inside expressions, without evaluating the expressions. For example, I have:

```
expr1 <- expression(if(x){
    return(y)
} else {
    return(z)
})
```

What I would like to do is get the following result assigned to "expr1":

```
expression(if(cos(x)){
    return(y)
} else {
    return(z)
 })
```

By doing something like this:

```
expr2 <- substitute(expr1, list(x=cos(x)))
```

But that doesn't work, since substitute doesn't evaluate it's first argument. And so I just get back the original variable:

```
expr1
```

Now [here](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-lang/R-lang_75.html) it says that to do substitutions in an expression assigned to a variable, I have to execute `substitute()` twice, followed by `eval()`, like this:

```
expr2 <- eval(substitute(substitute(e, list(x = cos(x))), list(e = expr1)))
```

When I execute this statement, I do get an expression assigned to "expr2", but it doesn't contain the required substitution:

```
expression(if (x) {
    return(y)
} else {
    return(z)
})
```

What syntax can I apply to "expr1" so that I get the result I would like assigned to "expr2", namely:

```
expression(if (cos(x)) {
    return(y)
} else {
    return(z)
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to do the trick

```
do.call('substitute', list(expr1[[1]], list(x=quote(cos(x)))))
# if (cos(x)) {
#     return(y)
# } else {
#     return(z)
# }
```

First I use `do.call` to pass the unevaluated expression as a parameter to `substitute()` rather than a double-`substitute`. Secondly, `expression()` is really like a container object. You're really interested in just changing the code block of the first element of your expression. You could have avoided the `expression()` and just used `quote()` to avoid the "unboxing"

```
expr2 <- quote(if(x){ return(y) } else { return(z) })
do.call('substitute', list(expr2, list(x=quote(cos(x)))))
```

Both of these will return a class of type "if". If you need to, you can wrap it in an `as.expression()`.

```
as.expression(do.call('substitute', list(expr1[[1]], list(x=quote(cos(x))))))
# expression(if (cos(x)) {
#     return(y)
# } else {
#     return(z)
# })
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Both solutions (yours and small's) produce an "if" class object.  I do in fact want to keep this an an expression, but when I wrap expr2 (i.e.:  expression(expr2)  ), as suggested, then I get "expression(expr2)" rather than "expression(if(cos(x)) ... )".  Clearly I'm not wrapping correctly.  Any guidance?

Comment: @user3990797 Sorry. I meant you can use `as.expression()` around the `do.call()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help and learned some stuff. I am adding the `as.expression()` note to my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `cos(x)` by wrapping it inside the `x = quote()` function of the nested `substitution()` ADDED: Per documentation, you can subset the expression using `[`, `[[`, or `$`. You have to subset the expression object using `[[` in the super substitute call. Try this:

```
expr2 <- eval(substitute(substitute(e, list(x=quote(cos(x)))), list(e = expr1[[1]])))

expr2
#if (cos(x)) {
#  return(y)
#} else {
#  return(z)
#}
```

To set `expr2` as an expression, call: `as.expression(expr2)`

Comment: Don't you need a `x=` in there somewhere? I copy/pasted this but it did not change anything for me. Still `if(x)`

Comment: Hmm that's strange, I just ran it again and now it returned the expression without the cos(x). Don't know what's going on, trying to fix now :/

Comment: @MrFlick I think I got it now :)

Comment: @small_data88:  Thanks!  Please see comment above, for MrFlick.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be:

```
x <- expr(cos(x)) 

expr2 <- expr(if (!!x) {
                return(y)
                 } else {
                 return(z) })
```